# Android: Remove ALL FragmentTransactions from the back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I add a bunch of FragmentTransactions to the back stack in one Tab, and I want to clear them ALL from the back stack when the user selects a different Tab. I can't find a method to clear stuff off the back stack, only methods to pop them off, and these don't even return the Fragment to you so you can close them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you add many Fragments to the backstack and want to remove them all you can do this: `popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)`

Comment: FYI: popBackStack-function is found in FragmentManager or SupportFragmentManager

Comment: My screen extends Fragment and i cant find popBackStack() method .. what can i do ??

Comment: @Coder getFragmentManager.popBackStack() or getSupportFragmentManager.popBackStack() if using the compat libs.

Comment: This answer works. But the doc says _ If null, only the top state is popped_ . So this behavior seems to be a bug. Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: In my case I have added too many fragments to backstack.Now the performance is very slow.I have tried using the above method.But it is not working.

Comment: `getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);` worked for me.

Comment: @tjlian616 it's because of FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE. documents says: "Flag for popBackStack(String, int) and popBackStack(int, int): If set, and the name or ID of a back stack entry has been supplied, then all matching entries will be consumed until one that doesn't match is found or the bottom of the stack is reached. *Otherwise, all entries up to but not including that entry will be removed.*" I saw otherwise part just in class docs but not in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

Answer (score 1):

Just remove them from the backstack using the `popBackStack()` methods.

Each fragment you pop is exactly the same as if the user had pressed the `BACK` button, and you don't do any special cleanup when the `BACK` button is pressed, right?